# Using BeautifulSoup to Scrape Revenue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

(Edit: Course wants us to use Soup, I know I'd rather use pd as well)

This is for a class I am taking so if able I would highly prefer a directional push rather than just an answer.

I have this site "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue" and I need to parse the quarterly revenue as a table.

This is how far I've gotten so far. (all necessary libs are imported)

```
html_data = requests.get("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue")

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data.text, "html.parser")

html_rev = soup.find("table",class_='historical_data_table table')

html_rev
```

This seems to have gotten me all the info but I can't form it into a table.

Comment: how exactly do You want to form it into a table? do You want graphical table? for that You may want to use some GUI libary like tkinter, otherwise You have to form it as text

Comment: There is more than one table, which one do you want to scrape

Comment: Unless you have to write parsing code, you might be better off using `pd.read_html` from `pandas`. See [https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#reading-html-content] for more info.

Comment: It will be formed into a pd.DataFrame I believe is how they want it.

I need the Quarterly Revenue with columns as 'Date' and 'Revenue'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the table. html_rev is the entire table. You need to improve your selection to just its data.

Since html_rev is a soup object, you can keep finding itens inside. For example:

```
table_header = html_rev.find("th")
print(table_header)
>>> <th colspan="2" ... </span></th>
```

This is the table header. So you can specify better which elements inside html_rev you want. You can use the find_all() method.

Each row in a table is defined by the tags `<tr><\tr>`.

Trying `rows = html_rev.find_all("tr")` will give you a list of each row. Each row then contains two td elements (table data).

For example, if you try to loop for each row and find all td elements:

```
for row in rows:
    print(row.find_all("td"))

>>> [<td style="text-align:center">2020</td>, <td style="text-align:center">$31,536</td>]
```

The result is a list with both td elements for each row.

Since you said you just want to be nudged to the right direction, I think you can get a gist of what you want and solve your question. It is straightforward. Select your table, then extract each row and from there you can extract each data. Remember that when you select the tag, to get the text inside it you need to select the .text attribute.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, Im going to sleep for the night and will attempt it again sometime tomorrow evening. I will send a reply if I do eventually pull it off.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to scrape the tables is to use [`pandas.read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html) from the [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) library.

For example, to get a `list` of all tables:

```
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue"

tables = pd.read_html(URL)
# This will access the first table, note the zero based indexing
print(tables[0])
```

Output:

```
   Tesla Annual Revenue(Millions of US $) Tesla Annual Revenue(Millions of US $).1
0                                     2020                                  $31,536
1                                     2019                                  $24,578
2                                     2018                                  $21,461
3                                     2017                                  $11,759
4                                     2016                                   $7,000
5                                     2015                                   $4,046
6                                     2014                                   $3,198
7                                     2013                                   $2,013
8                                     2012                                     $413
9                                     2011                                     $204
10                                    2010                                     $117
11                                    2009                                     $112
12                                    2008                                      $15
```